# How can I see cloudfoundry properties are defined on an application

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm deploying my CloudFoundry application, and want to configure some http routing properties as described in https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html

I think to configure what I want, I need to add this to my `manifest.yml`:

```
      properties:
        router:
          tracing:
            enable_zipkin: true
          balancing_algorithm: least-connection
```

Question: However, when I deploy, how do I know that these properties really take place, for example that the balancing_algorithm works as I configured?

I tried:

- `cf app` - doesn't show it
- `create-app-manifest` - creates a manifest, but there's no `properties:` in it
- Looking in [Stratos](https://stratos.app), I don't see the properties anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to enable zipkin, bit "cf env APP" usually shows user provided configuration.

Comment: I have zipkin enabled. `cf env <app>` doesn't show it anywhere - you see services under `VCAP_SERVICES`, a few general details at `VCAP_APPLICATION` and some User-Provided content.